# Install php 5.3.6 on ubuntu 10.04 64 bit

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, php53

I dont want to build from source and was looking to find some repository where I can simply do an `apt-get install php5` and get the latest version. Does anyone know of any reliable source I can use to do the same or is the only option I have to build it myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is PPA (Personal Package Archive) repository with PHP 5.3.6 at https://launchpad.net/~bjori/+archive/php5 with installation instructions. As I checked there is amd64 build as well (lucid).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bjori/php5
sudo apt-get update

sudo aptitude show php5
Package: php5
State: not installed
Version: 5.3.6-8ubuntu0ppa4~lucid1
Priority: optional
Section: php
Maintainer: Hannes Magnusson <bjori@php.net>
..

sudo aptitude install php5 php5-cli
php -v
PHP 5.3.6-8ubuntu0ppa4~lucid1 (cli) (built: May  5 2011 22:11:21) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
```

Note that you need to enable universe repository for that.